# Translate text of element that in turn has a child element

Tags: html, jquery

I'm trying to translate the texts of the following elements using jQuery, but when trying to translate the parent element I lose the child element and I don't know how to do it.

```
<p class="signup-link">
Don't have an account? 
<a href="https://aaa.com/registro">Sign Up</a>
</p>
```

I ask for your collaboration to resolve this matter, which is surely something easy for you.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Any [of these questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjquery%5D+get+text+without+children) will help you.